# which C++ header file declares strlen?

Tags: c++, strlen

Which library does `strlen()` belong to?

Does it belong to `cstring`? or `string`?

I tried the following code, and it does work:

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//withou include<string.h>

int main() {
    char * str="abc";
    cout<<strlen(str);
}
```

I set `str` equal to 3 and give the right answer 3.

Why does it work without including library string or cstring?

Should I include cstring or string there? string.h?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is already answered by the official documentation.


Comment: @ImranOmer this doesn't look like PHP. Rather, it looks like C++.

Comment: @JanDvorak: If it is answered in the official documentation, that seems to make it an on-topic question. Why would the docs go off-topic?

Comment: @Dvorak: I was confused since he doesn't used C++ as keyword. I thought he is using PHP. nevermind

Comment: @Thilo "offtopic" means "doesn't belong here and should be closed" rather "isn't about programming". I expect the closing system to change again in the future, hopefully clarifying this.

Comment: If "answered by documentation" is not a valid reason to close a question, then I'm switching to "lacks minimal understanding" as the official reason.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The underlying reason is a non-trivial difference between C and C++ (indirect inclusion of headers is only allowed in C++), yet the function is originally from C.

Comment: @JanDvorak many "good" questions on SO (measured by upvotes) can be answered with a cursory reading of the relevant spec; why single this one out?

Answer (score 20):

> Which library does strlen() belong to? Does it belong to cstring? or string?

Neither.  `cstring` and `string` are not *libraries*, they are *header files* which define the *interface* to various functions and classes.

The C language standard says that the `strlen` function is declared in the header file `<string.h>`.  In C++, including `<string.h>` places `strlen` into the global namespace, while including `<cstring>` instead places `strlen` into the `std` namespace.

The actual *implementation* of the `strlen` function is in the C standard library (aka `libc` or `CRT` on certain platforms).  Ordinarily, this is linked in with your executable at link time.

> Why it works without including library string or cstring?

In your particular compiler and toolchain, it just so happens that the header file `<iostream>` includes `<cstring>` into it, which means that any code that includes the former also gets the latter for free.  This is an **implementation detail** and should not be relied upon—if your compile your code with another compiler, you may suddenly find yourself in a sea of compiler errors.

The proper thing to do is to also include `<cstring>` here; even though it's not necessary with your particular compiler, it may be necessary with other compilers.

Comment: Not "aka `libc`"; that's a Unixism.

Answer (score 12):

In order to use `strlen()` you need to include the `<cstring>` header file:

```
#include <cstring>
```

This was the answer I was looking for, but I didn't find a direct answer here.

Answer (score 8):

The function `strlen()` is declared in the header file `<string.h>`.

From the  [GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html).

Comment: There's no such thing as a core function in C++.

Comment: I mentioned that is declared on string.h

Comment: I was confused for a moment with the php core function strlen() , but then see the code that is C code

Comment: Some of the `string` library is included in `<iostream>`, which you've included.

Comment: @user2756494 does iostream include string.h, perhaps?

Comment: @user2756494 The function prototypes in C are indications to the compiler that you can use for type checking hinting. When you don't include string.h, a default signature is assumed for the function.

Comment: Without `#include <iostream>` or any other `string` libraries, you can do nothing with `string`s.  With `#include <iostream>`, you can do everything except `string` io, which requires `#include <string>`

Comment: @nhgrif: And what does `<string>` have to do with `<cstring>` or `<string.h>`?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *pointer1="Idle hands are the devil's workshop.";

    int length;
    length=strlen(pointer1);

    char *pointer2;
    pointer2=new char(length+1);

    strcpy(pointer2,pointer1);

    cout<<"pointer 2:"<<pointer2;
    delete[] pointer2;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *string = "Hello World";
    printf("%lu\n", (unsigned long)strlen(string));
    return 0;
}
```

This program will print the value 11, which is the length of the string "Hello World". Character strings are stored in an array of a data type called char. The end of a string is found by searching for the first null character in the array.

From the GNU C Library